# Tag cleanup - burnination

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

In my recent perusal of the tags, I came across a couple that seemed unnecessary. Can we get rid of the following tags?

- [proof-that-1-plus-1-is-2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-that-1-plus-1-is-2) Seriously, why? Even [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags) doesn't have this as a tag. Also, there are no questions attached to it.
- [fun-stuff](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun-stuff) This seems to be a meta-tag that invites silliness. I'm all for a little lightheartedness in asking questions, but having this tag seems like it invites off-topic posts. Alternatively, we could make the synonym [fun-stuff](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun-stuff) → [soft-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question).

Comment: How on [tag:earth] (or is it [tag:earths]?) did I miss the [tag:proof-that-1-plus-1-is-2] tag when I was going through my massive tag wiki spree?

Comment: (a) Someone detagged it, so the tag will implode soon. @tpg would be proud. (b) I'm for the merge. Or just detagging.

Comment: Sorry for [tag:proof-that-1-plus-1-is-2]. I created it while doing a random test post (which I immediately deleted.) because I wanted to test a MathJax feature (which  can't be done at meta.)    I thought it would disappear along with the post .

Comment: Whatever it is, it's a reeeeeally specific tag .